# Extract number from string JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, extract

Does anyone know a way to extract numbers from a string in JavaScript?

**Example:**

```
1 banana + 1 pineapple + 3 oranges
```

My intent is to have the result in an array or JSON or something else.

**Result:**

```
[1,1,3]
```

Comment: Strings usually have quotes, so it's good to add them so there's no ambiguity about where the bytes are. Voting to close due to no attempt.

Answer (score 18):

```
var result= "1 banana + 1 pineapple + 3 oranges";
result.match(/[0-9]+/g)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
const s = "1 banana + 1 pineapple + 3 oranges";
const result = (s.match(/\d+/g) || []).map(n => parseInt(n));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This solution breaks if the string does not contain a number. The answer by @Amrutha is safest and does not strictly assume that the string has to contain a number.

Comment: @raychz Updated my answer to address cases where the string doesn't contain numbers. The solution by Amrutha that you're recommending doesn't extract numbers at all, it extracts numerical strings.

Comment: In ES6 you can use `s.match(/\d+/g)?.map(Number)`. Slight difference from the answer here: you get `undefined` rather than `[]` when there are no matches.

Answer (score 7):

Use this regex

- / -> start
- \d+ -> digit
- /g -> end and g for global match

```js
var str = "1 banana + 1 pineapple + 3 oranges",
  mats = [];
str.match(/\d+/g).forEach(function(i, j) {
  mats[j] = parseInt(i);
});
console.log(mats);
```

Comment: this and the answer from Robby are correct. So, marking any of this as answer will help future visitors.

Comment: This solution breaks if the string does not contain a number.  The answer by @Amrutha is safest and does not strictly assume that the string has to contain a number.