# NODE JS : How to recover data in number format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to recover the numbers (int) included in the tags that recover text (?innerText) for the moment. How can I do it ?

```
 const scraperObject = {
    url: 'https://stockx.com/fr-fr/dior-b713-cactus-jack-mocha',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        await page.goto(this.url);

        await page.waitForSelector('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');
        await page.click('#onetrust-reject-all-handler');

        const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
            //let result = [];
            let demandes = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > div > a.chakra-button.css-2zzyy5 > p').innerText;

            let offres = document.querySelector('#main-content > div > section:nth-child(3) > div.css-gg4vpm > div.css-0 > div.css-qt7qal > div.chakra-stack.css-1g42e87 > a > p').innerText;
            return {demandes, offres}
          })

          console.log(result);
          await browser
          browser.close()
          return result
    }
```

Comment: I want to tell my code to "Get only the numbers in this tag".

Comment: Can you show sample strings and the expected result from them? Have you tried writing some code to do this? This doesn't seem Puppeteer-specific, just plain old string manipulation once you remove the dressing. See, for example, [Extract number from string JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532450/extract-number-from-string-javascript)

Comment: Yes, I think so. 
requests: 'Buy at 1 365 €',
offers: 'Sell at 784 € or ask for more'.
I want to retrieve only the 1365 and 784 for the moment I retrieve all the text with ?innerText

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532532/6243352 should do the trick